# If Column A matches Column D, replace it with Column E (same row)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This picture should explain what I mean:

[image]

I want to swap my orders that have IDs into their real names, like the second order table.

Comment: So do you mean A, D and E?

Comment: Yes in the image, the title was generic.

Comment: What is your question? Can you please clarify in small words that I can understand?

Comment: I've edited the picture, it should make more sense now.

Comment: Well that makes a difference, you need to reference the sheets, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cell A10, then drag down:

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A3, Sheet1!$D$3:$E$5, 2)
```

Comment: Odd, I've entered this, nothing returns. I have to note that the cell format is just plain text.

Comment: @Flavor, so what does it show in the cell, completely nothing?

Comment: No, just the formula

Comment: @Flavor, that happens to me when I forget the '=' sign.  Though maybe you have calculation turned off (if so then hit 'F9').

Comment: Not having much luck still. But I've edited the picture, can you explain or link me how vlookup works?

Comment: Okay, silly me: I formatted the column to text only. No wonder formulas aren't working! Thanks for your help, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is `VLOOKUP`. You would use a static list of ID and string value, assign it to a Named region, and then use VLOOKUP to fetch the string for matching IDs.

Answer (score 0):

In cell `A9` use the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, $D$3:$E$5, 2, false)
```